# database path in web.config file while uploading in server in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have developed a project. i am uploading this project in a server. i could not connect this with the database.
what will be thw path in web.config file. help me please.this is my connection string in web.config file.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="bcharyaConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

should i use database path there?

```
  D:\microsoft sql server\data\bcharya.mdf
```

this path or
      D:\microsoft sql server\data\bcharya_log.LDF

Comment: do you have MS SQL2005 or 2008 installed ??

Comment: you need to check MS SQL server instance name also

Comment: connection string is all right i think

Comment: 2008 installed i am uploading this in real server

Comment: can you give summary of your error log please, can't make out like this

Comment: please follow this url: http://www.bcharyacorporation.com/bag101.aspx

Comment: may not be database problem is this application running well locally?

Comment: yes it is running there i am using my local server i think thats why it is running in local but while uploading in server what will be my connection string

Comment: may be IIS version problem , not sure are you using VS 2010?

Comment: VS2010 takes care of all , if server instance and virtual directory , publishing all are correct

Comment: then what should i do? @prasad and can you tell me the connectionstring database path

Comment: connection string is ok my friend see this <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: @Prased now please visit this url and see the error http://www.bcharyacorporation.com/bag101.aspx

Comment: You have two backslashes at the end of the row

Comment: Which hosting service are you using,is it your own server or did you purchase a server space,if so pls mention the service provider name,also try connecting support section of the service provider

Comment: opps.. ok well then also the same error @Amiram Korach

Comment: what i suggest check it on LAN first if all seems to be all right from any machine , then you must need administrators help not developer

Comment: ok. i am trying.. actually bcharya.mdf is the database name in my server but this is not mentioned in the connection string and the server location for the database is D:\microsoft sql server\data\bcharya.mdf and in connection string i am using aspnetdb.mdf should i use bcharya.mdf if so then how please tell me

Comment: your mdf file should be in websites /App_data/*.mdf

Comment: e.g. d:\mywebsite\App_data\aspnetdb.mdf

Answer (score 1):

**MDF Location**

Put your .MDF file in App_data folder.

**Connection string**

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="bcharyaConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bcharya.mdf;
      Integrated Security=True;
      User Id=myUsername;
      Password=myPassword;
      User Instance=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: ok. well while creating the database i have to create a user to access the database with some userid and password should i use this user id here? @sajanyamaha

Comment: yes @ManishSasmal add user/pass info also,**User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;**,I have EDITED above.

Comment: how can i Put my .MDF file in App_data folder. i can not find it. @sajanyamaha

Comment: Ok it seems you have not added the folder to your project,in your Visual Studio,right click on the project name-->select "Add ASP.NET Folder" from the menu-->Select "App_data".

Comment: APP_data folder is added. but i am uploading my project in server. in my computer it is running well.

Comment: upload this new folder as well,with the bcharya.mdf in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash "\" just after |DataDirectory| in your connection string:

**AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\bcharya.mdf;**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="bcharyaConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\bcharya.mdf;User Instance=true"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

|DataDirectory| ( Enclosed in pipe symbols ) is a substitution string that indicates the path to the database.

To set the `DataDirectory` property, call the `AppDomain.SetData` method. If you do not set the DataDirectory property, the following default rules will be applied to access the database folder:

1: For applications that are put in a folder on the user's computer, the database folder uses the application folder.
2: For web application the database folder uses  `App_Data` folder.

You can set the path in `Application_Start` method in your `Global.ascx.cs`

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"D:\microsoft sql server\data");
```

DO NOT Forget to change

**AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;**

to

**AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\bcharya.mdf;**

If the database is already attached to sql server change the connection to:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="bcharyaConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog = bcharya;User Instance=true"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

This way you don't need to set the |DataDirectory| path.

Comment: actually bcharya.mdf is the database name in my server but this is not mentioned in the connection string and the server location for the database is D:\microsoft sql server\data\bcharya.mdf and in connection string i am using aspnetdb.mdf should i use bcharya.mdf if so then how please tell me @NET3

Comment: can i use like this but not working <connectionStrings>
    <add name="bcharyaConnectionString" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> </connectionStrings>  @NET3

Comment: i am using visual studio 2010 @NET3

Comment: Is your sql server Express (SQLEXPRESS) edition or it's an other edition.

Comment: put your database files to "App_Data" folder and use "AttachDBFilename" technique